# Interpreting output of Stanford CoreNLP's Coreference Resolution

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there any API or a way to get **Stanford CoreNLP's Coreference Resolution output** in the form of **text** and not xml, so that it can be interpreted easily?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

There will be a human readable output at the bottom showing the coref information for the document.